# Not able to read image in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am writing my first code in openCV and VB2013 and I am not able to read image. I am trying with sample code.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
}
```

This is shown to me:

[image]

This is where I stored image:

[image]

Comment: your program expects a cmdline arg, the path to the image.

Comment: Where should I give that?
Should it not read from project folder as I kept picture in project folder.

Comment: " Should it not read from project folder " - hehe, not automatically. either run your prog from the cmdline like `prog path/to/image` or add the (absolute) path to image to 'program arguments' ( somewhere in your project debug settings)

Comment: Okay..
http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/07/change-contrast-of-image-or-video.html

I thought, something like this is possible then it will be great.
Tahnks

Comment: sure it is. just take your time..

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with OpenCV. You are mixing the command line and visual studio project. You have to pick up one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either we have to give location of image.
Or we can use command line where again we have to give location of image.
Or we can use code in such way.[enter link description here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/07/change-contrast-of-image-or-video.html)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer for your question?

Comment: Yes, actually I didn't gave proper way for locating image.

Comment: You are not addressing the real problem. You are mixing the command line and visual studio projects which means that your project will be terminated even if you provide the path in your source code. Having said that, you still can pass the main arguments from the visual studio but you are not doing so.

Comment: When we run VS than we will also command line.  I am only using VS not command line.
Thanks @Croco